# How to get access to a variable inside an arrow function?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass the value of **score** located inside the **getScoreText** arrow function as a prop to a child component, but I can't even seem to console logged it from the outside, is what I am trying to do possible?

```
const getScore = () => {
    const score = Math.round((met / total) * 100);
 
    if (score <= 33) {
      return BAD_SCORE;
    } else if (score <= 67) {
      return OKAY_SCORE;
    } else if (score < 100) {
      return GOOD_SCORE;
    } else if (score === 100) {
      return PERFECT_SCORE;
    }
  };
  console.log('getScoreText:', getScoreText(score));
```

Comment: Where have you defined `BAD_SCORE` and the like?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to calculate the score outside the function or return your score like an object with your constants, see the examples below:

```js
  // calculating the score outside the function
  const score = Math.round((met / total) * 100);
  console.log('getScoreText:', score));
```

or

```
  // returning object with the score and the scoreStatus
  const getScore = () => {
    const score = Math.round((met / total) * 100);

    if (score <= 33) {
      return { scoreStatus: BAD_SCORE, score };
    } else if (score <= 67) {
      return { scoreStatus: OKAY_SCORE, score };
    } else if (score < 100) {
      return { scoreStatus: GOOD_SCORE, score };
    } else if (score === 100) {
      return { scoreStatus: PERFECT_SCORE, score };
    }
  };
  console.log('getScoreText:', getScore());
```

In the both cases you can get the score